# using build.phonegap.com - how to reference cordova.js on pages other than index.html?

Tags: javascript, cordova, aem, phonegap-build

I have a multi-page news app built on Adobe CQ5 and using build.phonegap.com to compile. I can;t figure out how to reference cordova.js from all the HTML pages.

It's easy enough to use `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` on index.html, but the app is structured such that each article is its own HTML file on different directories. I can't hardcode the JS reference since I need it to be `<script src="../cordova.js"></script>` on one file and `<script src="../../cordova.js"></script>` on another and so on, depending on the directory of the HTML. Not to mention the path to assets and cordova.js is also different per device.

in a nutshell the structure is roughly like this:

```
/www/index.html <-- referencing cordova.js through <script src="cordova.js"></script>
/www/cordova.js
/www/content/breaking-news.html <-- this page needs to reference cordova.js too
/www/content/breaking-news/breaking-news-title.html <-- this page needs to reference cordova.js too
...
etc
```

How should I handle this? Is single page app the only solution? I am not concerned about performance since I've set up a contentsync system which will fetch zipped delta updates over the air and apply it to the app.

Comment: why cant you hardcode the path to cordova.js file?

Comment: Because i am using one template to generate the article pages, and i can't predict how deep the folder structure will go. I don't want to create different templates just to make this work

Comment: if you are not concerned about the performance you can generate the path to the cordova.js file when you create the article page.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path, like `../cordova.js` or `cordova.js` depends on the current location of the referencing resource, like `index.html` or `breaking-news.html`. You should rather use an absolute path: `/cordova.js`. It'll always reference the script from the site root, regardless the current web page path.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can't do that since the path to asset folder is different on each device. For android it's inside \assets\www\ and for iOS it's \Payload\appname.app\www\. I guess I can try to detect the device and pass the absolute path that way, but this doesn't feel right. I'm thinking there must be some sort of a path rewriter that can help me but no luck so far...